# Should you edit an answer to update it for DLC or content changes?

Tags: discussion

There is a pending edit for this answer to, [Where are all of the truck dealers?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/106439/37419), to a question on [euro-truck-simulator-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/euro-truck-simulator-2).

The original question asks about what trucks are available and at what dealerships.  The edit alters the accepted answer by updating with new dealerships and I assume new trucks.

Is updating someones answer to include new content correct?  I would assume that it is not.  You are now changing the content of someones post.  If you change it to something that is now wrong, you draw downvotes to that post that the original poster might not deserve.  I would think that the correct action is to post a new answer and point out that your answer details content added by DLC.

Comment: It's already been rejected. I'd say that means edits shouldn't update someone else's answer.

Comment: Just add another answer for DLC content. Not only will you then earn rep for it, but it keeps the 'vanilla' answer for those that don't own the DLC.

Comment: @Timelord64 Why is this a duplicate?  It's not touching the question at all, the question is even still valid.  It's about adding a new answer vs updating an existing answer.  (Preserving author intent vs consolidating information to make it easier for readers.)

Comment: @Troyen, OP is asking for a differant reason, but the underlying question is still the same

Comment: That supposed duplicate is hardly even related. That's about deleting questions which don't make any sense, not updating answers for new content.

Answer (score -1):

For a minor addition, why wouldn't you?

If the answer was correct at the time, and is still 90% correct minus some new details in a patch, is it really more beneficial to future readers to spread the information out in several different posts?  Especially if there are multiple patches/DLC that add content.  It's already pretty annoying when looking up an answer to a question for a game that has been out for a while and the highly upvoted accepted answer has what looks like good information, until you scroll down five answers to a new post that claims all the other answers are out of date.

When there are simply a few more monsters/truckers/spawn points/treasure locations to find and all the update does is add to an existing list, I think it would be preferable to tack it on to the highly visible accepted answer.  Adding a few bullet points isn't really changing author intent.

However, if a large portion of the answer has been rendered obsolete,  *then* writing your own answer may be preferable - especially if the original author is no longer interested in maintaining their answer.

Comment: Because you are inviting downvotes due to incorrect content.  That's why edits should be limited to formatting or grammar.  If I make your answer wrong, **I**, should get downvotes, not you.  Conversely, if I add content that would draw upvotes, I should get the upvotes.

Comment: You don't think people would notice and roll back content that was incorrect on an edit?  In practice, years later, most people have already voted on the answer anyway.

Comment: Not entirely, @Troyen. Updates can go unnoticed very easily. Also, you are able to remove or reverse your vote, if the question/answer has been edited since your vote. If the potentially incorrect information does recieve attention from the original voters, this could potentially be a **-2 per vote**, from the downvote and removed upvote.

Comment: @Timelord64 So you think it's a better user experience to add a new post for every patch on a question like [this](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/182501/what-are-greater-nephalem-rifts-and-how-do-they-work), instead of updating the highly-upvoted and accepted answers and making the users figure out which one of the now-five potentially-conflicting answers actually has all the up-to-date information?

Comment: Maybe the experience varies by tag.  The Blizzard games, popular as they are, seem to only get ~5 active questions a day at most, so even revisions are highly scrutinized.  In contrast, I've come across questions where a highly upvoted answer is long out of date, a newer answer is more correct, but not enough people employ downvotes/upvotes to correct the ordering for months or years afterward.

Comment: These problems have already been laid out. It has been discussed over and over again (which is why, at time of post, this question has 4 votes for closure as duplicate). You make good points **but you are not bringing any new arguments to the table**. I personally think we should be allowed to add a "this answer has not been updated to patch x.y.z", but others disgree. I invite you to look in to the other questions surrounding this. It takes experience to see the bigger picture, and other answers present it in a way that is much easier to understand.

Comment: As it stands, I believe we fall below average for "answers per question". I do not think that an answer per patch is ideal, but it is also a gross over exaggeration. Remember, SE is not designed with the intention of only having the one absolute answer.

Comment: I'm surprised this is even being debated. Of course you should update it. If the user is still active, they'll see the edit and can roll it back if they don't like it. Right? Pretty sure I've had that happen to me. If they don't roll it back then they've approved the edit and there's no issue with their rep being tied to that decision.